# Unable to disable Android checkstyle error

Tags: android, gradle, checkstyle

I have the following output from the lint step in android.

```
<file name="src/main/java/com/amazon/mycomp/application/metrics/MetricsUtil.java">
    <error line="15" severity="error" message="Class MetricsUtil should be declared as final."     source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.design.FinalClassCheck"/> 
</file>
```

So I tried to disable the checks using the following :-

```
@SuppressLint("all")
```

in the source file.

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    disable 'FinalClassCheck'
}
```

but neither of the two work.

I honestly do not care about my class being final or not. I want my build to work. Its not failing when unit testing and/or integration testing.

I tried looking up for help in https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html but nothing that came out as usable.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has to be inside of android block

```
android {
.
.
.
   lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
      disable 'FinalClassCheck'
  }
```

in Picasso they have this in there root

```
  plugins.apply('checkstyle')

  task('checkstyle', type: Checkstyle) {
    configFile rootProject.file('checkstyle.xml')
    source 'src/main/java'
    ignoreFailures false
    showViolations true
    include '**/*.java'

    classpath = files()
}
    }
.
.
.
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.findByName('check').dependsOn('checkstyle')
}
```

you check here https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/build.gradle
and the checkstyle.xml file is also in the root

Comment: It is inside an android block.

Comment: How are you configuring your checkstyle usually there is a file checkstyle.xml that contains all the rules you want to be verified. Also how are you running are you using command line ?

Comment: A wrapper over the command line. No I am not using a custom checkstyle file. Whatever default comes with gradle I presume.

Comment: Can you type the comand line you trying to run ? if you look to Picasso for instance they have there checkstyle file https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/checkstyle.xml